# Rotate TextBlock on WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a project where I'm attempting to display a DXF file in a WPF canvas. I've used a scale transform in order to change the canvas coordinate system to match a DXF coordinate system but now when I'm creating TextBlocks they show up mirrored. Is there a way to create these TextBlocks in the code behind file mirrored to match the scale transformed canvas?

```
<Canvas x:Name="map_page_canvas" Width="800" Height="500" ClipToBounds="True"
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" MouseWheel="ViewportMouseWheel">
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX="1" CenterY="1" />
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <MatrixTransform x:Name="transform"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            </Canvas>
```

```
public void DrawMtext(List<(string, double, List<double>)> canvasMtextList)
        {
            foreach ((string, double, List<double>) mtext in canvasMtextList)
            {
                TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
                textBlock.Text = mtext.Item1;
                textBlock.FontSize = Math.Ceiling(mtext.Item2 * 5);

                Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, mtext.Item3[0]);
                Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, mtext.Item3[1]);

                map_page_canvas.Children.Add(textBlock);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my DrawMtext method like this to solve it:

```
public void DrawMtext(List<(string, double, List<double>)> canvasMtextList)
        {
            foreach ((string, double, List<double>) mtext in canvasMtextList)
            {
                TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
                textBlock.Text = mtext.Item1;
                textBlock.FontSize = Math.Ceiling(mtext.Item2 * 5);

                Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, mtext.Item3[0]);
                Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, mtext.Item3[1]);

                ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
                scaleTransform.ScaleY = -1;
                TransformGroup textScaleTransform = new TransformGroup();
                textScaleTransform.Children.Add(scaleTransform);
                textBlock.RenderTransform = textScaleTransform;

                map_page_canvas.Children.Add(textBlock);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You do not need a TransformGroup for a single transform. You could as well assign `textBlock.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;`. Or just `textBlock.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1, -1);`. Also note that you may need to set the `RenderTransformOrigin` property, in case you do not want to transform around the upper left corner of the element.